# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and Sql Server 2016 Schema Compare

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2016, schema-compare

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and that all went smoothly however, now when I attempt to do a Schema Compare from a data project against a Sql Server 2016 database it shows that i needs to create all objects in the database.  This worked fine before this update.

I get the following error when the compare initializes:

> An error occurred while attempting to reverse engineer elements of
>   type
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlDatabaseCredential:
>   Batch Command during reverse engineer failed with Error Code:
>   -2146232060 Line Number: 2267 Error Message: Invalid column name `compression_delay`. Invalid column name `compression_delay`.

Does anyone know what is causing this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you checked whether you have that column ?

Comment: Yeah, I don't have anything in my database with the name "compression_delay"

Comment: Mine also broke after update 2, same error, any luck in finding a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what caused this problem to happen but I ended up detaching all my databases, uninstalling SQL Server and doing a fresh install.  After that all scripts and VS data compares worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found an update/patch for VS 2015 Update 2. Applying the patch fixed the issue.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt695655.aspx#