# Remote connections for SQL Server 2016 from Visual Studio 2015 error could not open a connection

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, named-pipes

I just installed SQL Server 2016 on my home server. I'm trying to connect to it from Visual Studio 2015 from my desktop PC, and repeatedly getting the well-known error:

> An error occurred while attempting to reverse engineer elements of
>   type
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlDatabaseCredential:
>   Batch Command during reverse engineer failed with Error Code:
>   -2146232060 Line Number: 2267 Error Message: Invalid column name compression_delay. Invalid column name compression_delay.

Comment: So what's unclear about the _well-known_ error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and Sql Server 2016 Schema Compare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872528/visual-studio-2015-update-2-and-sql-server-2016-schema-compare)

Comment: i was not aware of update/patch for VS 2015 Update 2, will try and update question

Answer (score 1):

See this question with the exact same error message.
[Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and Sql Server 2016 Schema Compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872528/visual-studio-2015-update-2-and-sql-server-2016-schema-compare)

The fix there was Updating Visual Studio with this patch.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx

Try updating Visual Studio and see if the error persists!

Good luck!

Comment: i was not aware of update/patch for VS 2015 Update 2, will try and update, thanks